# RDFa Reader extraction tool

Tags: extract, rdf, rdfa

I am beginner in RDF and I want to extract RDF from HTML
I am using GRDDL but it doesn't work with me well I am getting Security Exception every time:(
will you please suggest to me another tool ?

appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you please expand your question a little more with what tools you've tried already and the full details of the error message as this will make it much easier for people to answer the question

Answer (score 5):

I normally use rapper which you can download and install from [Redland's libraries](http://librdf.org/raptor/)

Once you have it installed you can simple do things like:

`rapper -i rdfa -o turtle http://stores.bestbuy.com/492/`

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of RDFa parsers at http://rdfa.info/dev/